# setting up FTP for Linux VPS Server with GUI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ftp, vps

I have a 1and1 Linux VPS server with ubuntu 10.4 installed. We need to be able to FTP files to  it using a GUI as not everyone is in IT or happy with command-line stuff.

Do I need to install vsftpd firstly?

Is there a GUI that will work with a Linux server? my boss likes Cyberduck.

If so is setting up the FTP connection the same as with a windows server? i.e enter in the IP and then a username.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to be able to log into the VPS and open an FTP GUI from the server or just use a GUI client from the other computers?

Comment: Hi dewitt I just need to be able to open a connection to the server from other computers, in the same way one would traditionally use cyber duck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything on the VPS to use a GUI FTP client.

Here's the instructions for setting up an FTP server on ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Once the once the FTP server software is installed on the VPS, you should be able to FTP either from the command line or any GUI tool you wish to use.  The GUI clients shouldn't care what kind of OS the server has.

And yes, FTP works the same on Ubuntu as on a Windows PC.  You put in the ip address and username (and password if you set that up), and connect to the server.